# How to change a value in url - index to home - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cpanel

I have an index.html file and in my htaccess, I have removed the .html so that something like www.xxx.com/index#about would work.

I have a question inregards to wanting to change the url so instead of showing index, it shows home. I changed index.html to home.html but that messed things up as it was looking for index.

Is there a way to set it in htaccess so that index is replaced with home in url?

Comment: Can you show us your current .htaccess?

Comment: Are you looking for `DirectoryIndex`?

Comment: It was that. DirectoryIndex home.html and then change index.html file to home.html. Thanks